# ipa root certificate signing

Tags: certificate-authority, freeipa

I am trying to get my ipa certificate signed by openca and its getting rejected due to hostname.

```
The following hostnames were rejected because the system couldn't link them to your 
account, if they are valid please verify the domains against your account.
Rejected: Certificate Authority
```

does any one know how to either generate the certificates manually so all the information can be included or if there is some setting I am missing that is causing this error on the initial install of the ipa server.

host is centos 6.3 I have installed ipa-server with dns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there are 3 types how FreeIPA can blend in a existent certificate environment:

1. No blending - FreeIPA is simply installed with own PKI and self-signed CA certificate
2. External CA - FreeIPA is installed with own PKI, but it's CA certificate is signed with external certificate authority. This requires the external CA to allow sub CAs, which is not so common. I think this is the root cause of your problem.
3. CA-less installation - FreeIPA does not configure own CA, but uses signed **host** certificates from external CA. This should work in your case. This [feature](http://www.freeipa.org/page/V3/CA-less_install) was introduced in [FreeIPA 3.2.0](http://www.freeipa.org/page/Releases/3.2.0).

Thus, my advise would be to try CA-less installation with certs signed by openca.

Comment: I was planning to use cacert.org. I will have to double check and see if it allows sub ca's

Comment: just checked and there is a way but not with the certificate I had. The information was greatly appriciated. Just to verify does that mean that the ipa associated clients will be able to get a host certificate from the freeipa or is that something that has to be assigned seperatly?

Comment: You will be able to get client host certificate for options Self-signed CA and External CA options as there is a real PKI server running in FreeIPA server. With CA-less, there is no FreeIPA PKI and you will need to assign the host cert separately from your PKI (cacert.org or other at your disposal).